# Error: Could not make a database connection using user@host

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is how my website connected to mysql database untill php was upgraded to version 5.4

```
public function core() {        
  if (!@$this->dbCon = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user,$this->password)) {
    exit('Error: Could not make a database connection using ' .
      $this->user . '@' . $this->host);
  }
```

But now, I get `Error: Could not make a database connectionz using user@host`.
How do I rewrite this code using PDO?

Comment: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: don't output a fixed/useless error message, `exit(mysql_error())` will TELL you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

mysql functions are deprecated. Try to use mysqli_connect function.

Comment: ok thanks. i've tried to use PDO. public function core() {
  if (!@$this->$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=agas_western;charset=utf8', 'agas_western', 'bndsg7')); {
        exit(mysql_error());
     }
     if (!mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->dbCon)) {
        exit(mysql_error());
     } HOW DO I CHANGE THIS BELOW LINE TO PDO?